# How to get the month, day and year from Calendar.get_date separately in python?

Tags: python, pycharm, calendar, format

I need the year, month and day separately, or simply convert it in datetime, because I need another format such as yyy-month-dd from the Calendar `get_date` method.

```py
cal = Calendar(ventanaEvento, selectmode="day", year=2022, month=1, date=1)
cal.place(x=450, y=100)
print(cal.get_date())
```

prints: 1/19/22 month, day, year.

This just returns a string which I do not need, because I need the numbers separately or a different format: yyyy-mm-dd.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: print(cal.get_date()) is this printing 1/19/22 this ?

Comment: Yes, I need that string but with another format and get its values for different purposes but that string is not useful for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(date)
```

Y-year,
m-month,
d-day,
H-hours,
M-minutes,
S-seconds

Comment: I am using Calendar , and its get_date method() from which I cannot get year , month , day separately, I need the calendar not datetime library.